# How would I pass data from multiple activities to a single activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

This may seem like a dumb question, but let's say I have an app where I have a multi-activity form:
Activity 1, 2, 3,..., n
At the bottom of activity 1 to 1-n, there is a "next" button which would ideally send the user-entered data to activity "n" and ALSO moves from activity "k" to activity "k+1" where "k < n".

In activity "n", there's a button which sends all the data from it's form and the previous forms to a database.

Do I need to pass data from activity to activity like a relay race or would I be able to directly pass data from activity "k" to the "n"th activity while also launching the "k+1"th activity? If the latter is possible, how would I do that?

FYI I'm sort of a newbie to Android dev as you can probably tell.

Comment: I don't have any problem with @Jacks answer, but this sounds to me more like a use case for multiple `Fragments` (in one `Activity`), instead of multiple `Activities`. You can get the two to look the same. The benefit is, `Fragments` are somewhat more `tightly coupled` than `Activities`. You could simply store all your data in the `Activity`. You'd still need to serialize it during an `onSaveInstanceState()`, though.

Comment: @greeble31 - it's clearly mentioned in the answer that there are many other ways to achieve this , this question was especially asked about activities not about fragments thats the reason i have answered a way using only activities. Author has all the rights to pick a way that he may think useful. My answer is also a way to achieve this.

Comment: @Jacks take it easy, I'm not the downvoter. I was simply indicating my approval of your answer, and adding some thoughts of my own.

Comment: no problem with the downvote. I understand its the way SO works. just curious to update my intentions of answering in this way. cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to pass it to each activity. You can just use a Shared Preference in each activities to save data, and finally in the Last Activity where you can fetch the data from Shared Preference and submit it to the database

Here is the example how it is done in Android

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

There are many other ways to achieve though. this would be a simple and basic one.